# Count and group by number of records in select query result set

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

I have a table with `emp_id, income`, etc.

I wish to get number of records for a query like

```
select * from table_name where income <= 500;
```

There will be at least 3 such income groups - which will b given at report generation time.

Further I wish to get all 3 Counts - and group the results by the count of their respective income group - all this in a single query.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What are your groups? Why not `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t GROUP BY {some_condition}` ?

Comment: See CASE...WHEN...THEN...END

Comment: Provide us with sample

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ,if this doesn't suite your need you may need to write a custom stored procedure

```
SELECT 
sum((income <= 500)) as range1,
sum((income <= 1000)) as range2 
FROM table_name
```

[sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b93b/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE expression to create your categories, and then a GROUP BY to summarize the categories.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num, 
       CASE WHEN income IS NULL    THEN 'missing'
            WHEN income <= 0       THEN '0'
            WHEN income <= 500     THEN '1 - 500'
            WHEN income <= 1000    THEN '501-1000'
                                   ELSE '> 1000' 
       END AS category
  FROM table_name 
 GROUP BY category WITH ROLLUP
```

Including the WITH ROLLUP clause will give you an overall count as well as the count of each category.